# generate SHA1 hash ID for base64 input data (file data in base64)

Tags: javascript, sha1, cryptojs

I'm trying to generate SHA1 hash ID for the input, input is nothing but file content in `base64` format.

To be clear input will be `base64` data, output will be SHA1 hash ID

I have been using CryptoJS library as shown in below code. But no luck the generated hash ID is different than the actual hash needed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href=""/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    </head>
    <body lang="en">
        <form id="test">
            <p>
                <label>Text</label><br>
                <textarea id="text" style="width: 500px; height: 200px">This is the secret message</textarea>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="crypto-js.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sha1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#test').on('submit', function() {
                    var b64data= $('#text').val();
                    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(b64data);
                    var result = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash);
                    console.log(result);

                    return false;
                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output from my code:

> 6bc205c87e54d2d114a880f25d227b75639a9d74

Expected output:

> fca9cdfd98590aa4c417b412c8331dfb2faf2253

Input `base64` sample: Unable to attach as length exceed Stack Overflow body limit.

Comment: Is your expected hash also generated from the base64 encoded file, or its binary content?

Comment: yes, Actually file will be converted/encoded to base64 and the same will be input to my HTML page for which i may need to generate hassh ID and display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed my code converting base64 to words array like below

```
var words = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(b64data);
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(words);
var result = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash);
```

it worked for me. hope it will help others as well